# how to set a mp3 from raw folder as ringtone on button click?

Tags: android, android-studio

```js
package com.techjapreet.shivshankarkiringtone;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class ringtone_tab extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button clk1;
    Button clk2;
    Button clk3;
    Button clk4;
    Button clk5;
    Button clk6;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    Button setting1;

    Button setting2;

    Button setting3;

    Button setting4;

    Button setting5;

    Button setting6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtone_tab);


        setting1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting1);
        setting2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting2);
        setting3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting3);
        setting4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting4);
        setting5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting5);
        setting6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting6);




        clk6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play6);

        clk5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play5);

        clk4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play4);

        clk3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play3);

        clk2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play2);

        clk1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play1);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    }

    public void setSetting1(Button setting1) {
        this.setting1 = setting1;

        setting1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setRingTone("shiv_shankar");

                private void setRingTone(String:String soundName;
                soundName){
                    File ringFile;
                    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+soundName+");
                            File ringFile = new File(uri.getPath());
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringFile.length());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    StringBuffer mCr;
                    Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);


                    try {
                        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                    } catch (Throwable t) {

                    }
                }

            }

           

    public void setBtn_play6(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_vandana);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void setBtn_play5(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_tandav_mantra);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }



    public void setBtn_play4(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shiv_om);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

   



    public void setBtn_play2(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_aaradhna);
        mediaPlayer.start();


    }


    public void setBtn_play1(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shankar);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void stopPlayer(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {mediaPlayer.stop();}
    }

}
```

I am making an app which plays the mp3 file from a raw folder on button click and its working well but now I have seen all the codes on the internet and none of them helped me. I have attached the codes and XML file to this.the problem is I created a settings and play icon next to each text view to play each mp3 when user clicks, playing mp3 works but I don't know how to set an mp3 file as ringtone when user clicks on single button next to each playable file please can anyone provide me the complete code to set each file when clicked on settings icon as mp3 from raw folder. I would be thankful to you.

[image]

```js
package com.techjapreet.shivshankarkiringtone;


import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class ringtone_tab extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button clk1;
    Button clk2;
    Button clk3;
    Button clk4;
    Button clk5;
    Button clk6;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    Button setting1;

    Button setting2;

    Button setting3;

    Button setting4;

    Button setting5;

    Button setting6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ringtone_tab);


        setting1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting1);
        setting2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting2);
        setting3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting3);
        setting4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting4);
        setting5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting5);
        setting6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_setting6);




        clk6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play6);

        clk5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play5);

        clk4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play4);

        clk3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play3);

        clk2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play2);

        clk1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play1);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    }

    public void setSetting1(Button setting1) {
        this.setting1 = setting1;

        setting1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
    }

    public void setBtn_play6(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_vandana);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void setBtn_play5(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_tandav_mantra);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }



    public void setBtn_play4(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shiv_om);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    public void setBtn_play3(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shiv);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }



    public void setBtn_play2(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_aaradhna);
        mediaPlayer.start();


    }


    public void setBtn_play1(View v)
    {
        stopPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shiv_shankar);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void stopPlayer(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {mediaPlayer.stop();}
    }

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play1" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play2" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play3" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play4" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview3"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview4"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play6" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview5"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First you need to covert raw to uri and then you set as ringtone

Comment: @AnasMehar can you please complete my code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the mp3 is saved in the raw folder as

> notification_sound.mp3

```
private void setRingTone(String soundName){
    Uri uri1=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+soundName+");
    File ringFile = new File(uri1.getPath());
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringFile.getAbsolutePath());
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, rindFile.length());
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

       Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringFile.getAbsolutePath());
       Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);


       try {
           RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
       } catch (Throwable t) {

       }
}
```

and In clickListener call

```
setting1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             setRingTone("shiv_vandana")

            }
        });
```

Comment: so i have to add this method in onclick listner like i created in the code above please see onlick listner of setting1 button

Comment: Yes and don't forget to pass name of audio raw file which you want to set as ringtone.

Comment: how to pass the audio file name please tell me sir

Comment: sir i have added the code you told me to add but now i see error  [link](https://prnt.sc/p9x2c2)

Comment: In Screen shot way are  you setRingTone method create inside clickListener? 
setRingTone() this method in your class and call in your onclickListener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199850/discussion-between-anas-mehar-and-jaspreet-singh).